# v-model on Component returning type string instead of type null

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, html-select

[Link to Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

I'm trying to create a Vue 3 component that can handle a v-model binding. The component contains a simple <select>.

The 1st <option> contains a null value with the inner text 'Default placeholder'. The others <option> contain actual values.

If I try to select the option with the null value, rather than returning null it returns the inner text 'Default placeholder'.

I need it to return null.

I can get the null value (see the changeValue() method) but it feels hacky using event.target.selectedOptions[0]._value.

If I try to build the same functionality without using a custom component using v-model then it works as expected.

**Child Component**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    methods: {
        changeValue(event) {
            // Output the event for testing purposes
            console.dir(event);
            console.log(event.target.value);
            console.dir(event.target.selectedOptions[0]);
            console.log(event.target.selectedOptions[0].text);
            // This is the correct value but im unsure if I can use it.
            console.log(event.target.selectedOptions[0]._value);
            console.log(typeof event.target.value);

            // Emit the handler
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value);
        }
    },
    name: 'HtmlSelect',
    props: ['modelValue'],
})
</script>
<template>
    <select :value='modelValue' @input="changeValue">
        <option :value="null">Should be null. Get inner text.</option>
        <option :value="1">Number: 1</option>
        <option value="1">String: 1</option>
        <option :value="'Some Text'">String: Some Text</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

The parent instance is not doing anything special.

**Parent Component**

```
<html-select v-model="someVal"></html-select>
```

** Edit ** I've simplified the example component to better illustrate the error. Added a link to a working example.

Comment: i think that selectVals must be an array of objects. The objects must be 2 properties, ``value`` (for send trough form) and ``label`` (for see it in DOM). The first object of this array must be ``{value: null, label: 'Default placeholder'}``

Comment: The issue is not related to selectVals I included the selectVals just so I could render some example values in a loop. I could replace the v-for with a pure HTML list of options and Vue will still return the inner HTML text of the option if the value bound to it is null or undefined.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Comment: Not too sure how it can be more clear? A Vue component using v-model is not returning null.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to how `<option>` gives you a value. `null` is an absence of a value. If the value of the option is nullish, then text between opening and closing tags returned. Try use `"0"` instead of `null` and check for `"0"`, not `null`, and then replace `"0"` with `null` if you really need `null`

Comment: I think it may be a bug with Vue. Vues documentation is pretty clear, v-model should be able to return dynamic types such as Object Literals. No matter what you return you get a string if v-model is used on a custom component. If you just use v-model on some HTML it works as intended.

Comment: How about passing a callback through the props from App component to that custom select component? In the custom component you call a callback every time the component changes value and this value is handled by App component

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain the values original type then you must use a computed getter / setter within the component along with a v-model binding.

[Demo Here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

### Working Code

```
export default defineComponent({
    computed: {
        value: {
            get() {
                return this.modelValue;
            },
            set(value: any) {
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', value);
            }
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selectOptions: {
                'Null Option': null,
                'Numeric Option': 1,
                'String Option': 'String'
            }
        }
    },
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    name: 'HtmlSelect',
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: String,
            default: null
        }
    },
    template: '<select v-model="value">' +
        '<option v-for="(option, i) in selectOptions" :value="option">{{ i }}</option>' +
        '</select>'
})
```